# Selection of multiple patterns of a string

Tags: r

I have a string

`hw <- "mw61e10"`

I want to select in one go multiple patterns e.g.

`m` `w6` `1e10`

`str_sub(hw, 4, 7)` to get `1e10`

Is there the possibility to pass multiple patterns to `str_sub`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define vectors with the string positions at which you want to match and use these as arguments in `str_sub`:

```
a <- c(1,2,4)
b <- c(1,3,7)

str_sub(hw, a, b)
[1] "m"    "w6"   "1e10"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can use `substring`

```
substring(hw, a, b)
#[1] "m"    "w6"   "1e10"
```

The 'a', 'b' objects are from @ChrisRuehlemann

Comment: Would be nice if you gave credit to @ChrisRuehlemann for the idea to define `a` and `b`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann sorry, i didn't notice that it was not in the OP's post.  You are right.  I updated with credits to your post